# How to simulate tuples and sets in C#?

Tags: c#, python, data-structures, set, tuples

I want to use some features of python like as Tuples and Sets in c#. should I implement them? or there are already implemented? could anybody knows a library of dynamic data structures for .net languages?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.NET 3.5 has [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495294.aspx).

.NET 4.0 will have a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd942829.aspx) class. As noted in the article, earlier version of .NET do contain KeyValuePair< TKey, TValue > which is similar to a Tuple< T1, T2 >, with the main difference being that KeyValuePair requires that TKey is unique.

Comment: "... which is just like a Tuple", albeit a 2-tuple only.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, I meant to specify a 2-tuple. Edited and fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @nawfal The only difference between KeyValuePair and a 2-tuple is the fact that a 2-tuple could have multiple entries for the same "first element" (or key in KVP). Even the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx) says that a 2-tuple is similar to the KeyValuePair structure.

Comment: @KevinCrowell And that difference is significant. The documentation says the structure is similar, but the use case in my opinion is completely different. I have seen people showing tendency to use a keyvaluepair, when unique key constraint is never a requirement. One should be aware a 2-tuple is not a replacement for a keyvaluepair or viceversa. You can edit your answer to mention that too (in parenthesis or so). Instead of "just like" you can use "similar to" with the difference mentioned. But a good answer otherwise :)

Answer (score 3):

For Sets, HashSets (a .NET 3.5 feature) do the trick quite well.

A partial answer, for tuples:

- .NET 4.0 provides [some] support for [**tuples**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple%28VS.100%29.aspx).
- Earlier versions of C# can use the anonymous type (I think introduced in .Net 2.0, 3.0 for sure, with all the LINQ stuff).

Neither of these approaches are as convenient as with Python; the main handicap comes from the fact that C# is statically typed.  However the C# 4.0 Tuple class has factory-like static methods which make the creation of tuples easier (up to 8-tuple, i.e. tuples with 8 members).  For example one can have

```
  var customer1 = Tuple.Create("John", "Smith", 14, 5.33, "202-123-444");
```

Using anonymous type can be done as follow. The main drawback of this approach is that one needs to explicitly name the elements of the "tuple" (although this naming can be implicitly "projected" if the values used for initialization are "projected" from another object.

```
  customer1 = new Customer {
                Name = "John",
                Surname = "Smith",
                NumberOfVisits = 14,
                CurrentBalance = 5.33,
                PhoneNr = "202-123-444"
  };
```

Comment: @mjv: C# is a more *statically* typed language.  Both C# and Python are strongly typed.

Comment: @quamrana : quite right. That's what I meant; now edited accordingly.

Comment: anonymous types was added in C# 3.0/.NET 3.5. .NET 3.0 was only BCL stuff no changes to the languages

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with a .NET Framework earlier than already mentioned, [Wintellect Power Collections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/) might prove of some interest - it has `Pair` and `Triple` for 2- and 3-tuples, and collections such as `Set`, `Bag`, and `Ordered` flavours of both.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from implementing 4.0's `Tuple` yourself.

(By the way, there's nothing particularly 'dynamic' about data structures like these in and of themselves)